# Can I make an HTTP request that only uses HTTP/2

Tags: go

I am working on some scripts to test our infrastructure at various levels. I am trying to make tests to verify functionality for clients both with and without http2. [The docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) specify how to *disable* http2 by overriding `Transport.TLSNextProto`, but I can't find any way to **require** http2.

Is there a way to require an http request uses http/2 only? Or if not is there any kind of field or hook to see if it used http2 or not?

Comment: Can you send an "Upgrade" header?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Response.ProtoAtLeast(2, 0)` to check if it came in over version 2. See: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response.ProtoAtLeast